# When is it ok to be !ok() with C++20 chrono dates?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

The `<chrono>` library allows dates to silently fall into a state of !ok().  For example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    auto date = 2023y/October/31;
    cout << date.ok() << '\n';
    date += months{1};
    cout << date.ok() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

[Demo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YJSKryKXQ503eLZG)

I get that Oct 31 is a valid date and that Nov 31 is not.  But why isn't Nov 31 an error (assert or throw)?  Or why does it not snap back to Nov 30, or roll over into Dec 1 as other date libraries do?

Is it not error prone to just let Nov 31 silently exist?

Comment: It's a bit inconsistent that you can add a month and get a !ok() date. But you can't add days at all and get a compiler error. Well, it's C++. You get used to all it's §$%& design choices. https://wandbox.org/permlink/BMr5uWSRzxPwjCrl

Comment: Here is a FAQ on that issue: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/FAQ#day_arithmetic. But perhaps that would make a good SO Q/A as well.  Thank you for the suggestion.  And here is your example with working syntax: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Fyxa6J2MEARHg4ZG

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a new title.  I prefer my original title, so I've changed it back.

Comment: @user3840170 the title is perfectly ok. Please don't vandalize the question. It's a play on words and it expresses very well the content and it does it better than your suggestion as the post is not about adding months specifically but addresses the underlying philosophy and considerations  for choosing this mechanism of dealing with invalid dates.

Comment: I am not vandalizing the question, and I wish my comments were not being deleted without being actually addressed instead of dismissed.  I stand by my edit; the title is basically as bad as [“Memory and Mr. Struct”](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8199793/1); vague to the point of uselessness.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The question, in part, almost answers itself:

> Or why does it not snap back to Nov 30, or roll over into Dec 1 as other date libraries do?

Because there isn't any consistent practice on what should happen, `<chrono>` leaves it up to the client for what should happen.  Therefore literally *anything* the programmer can dream up and implement *can* happen.

For example, here is how to snap back to Nov 30:

```
auto date = 2023y/October/31;
date += months{1};
if (!date.ok())
    date = date.year()/date.month()/last;
```

And here is how to roll into December:

```
auto date = 2023y/October/31;
date += months{1};
if (!date.ok())
    date = sys_days{date};
```

The former is quite obvious what it is doing in the code.  But the latter deserves a little more explanation:  Conversion to `sys_days` is just converting a `{year, month, day}` data structure into a `{count_of_days}` data structure.  And that conversion is allowed to happen even if the day field is overflowed.  This is just like the C timing API between `tm` and `time_t`.

And just like there is no invalid `time_t`, there is no invalid `sys_days`.  It is just a count of days since (or before) 1970-01-01.  And when you convert that count back to `{year, month, day}`, it results in a valid (`.ok() == true`) `year_month_day`.

Obviously the programmer could also declare an error:

```
auto date = 2023y/October/31;
date += months{1};
if (!date.ok())
    throw "oops!";
```

One cool aspect of this behavior (prior to corrections added by the programmer) is that the date arithmetic follows normal arithmetic rules:

```
 z = x + y;
 assert(x == z - y);
```

I.e., if you add a month, and then subtract a month, you are guaranteed to get back the same date:

```
auto date = 2023y/October/31;
assert( date.ok());
date += months{1};
assert(!date.ok());
date -= months{1};
assert( date.ok());
assert(date == 2023y/October/31);
```

[Demo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Md9tAz7JQ1C5ZyrC)

And sometimes the correct action is none of flag-error, roll-over or snap-back.  Sometimes the correct action is to *ignore* the invalid date!

Consider this problem:

I want to find all dates for some year `y` which are the 5<sup>th</sup> Friday of the month (because that is party day or whatever). Here is a very efficient function which collects all of the 5<sup>th</sup> Fridays of a year:

```
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

std::pair<std::array<std::chrono::year_month_day, 5>, unsigned>
fifth_friday(std::chrono::year y)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    constexpr auto nan = 0y/0/0;
    std::array<year_month_day, 5> dates{nan, nan, nan, nan, nan};
    unsigned n = 0;
    for (auto d = Friday[5]/January/y; d.year() == y; d += months{1})
    {
        if (d.ok())
        {
            dates[n] = year_month_day{d};
            ++n;
        }
    }
    return {dates, n};
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto current_year = year_month_day{floor<days>(system_clock::now())}.year();
    auto dates = fifth_friday(current_year);
    std::cout << "Fifth Friday dates for " << current_year << " are:\n";
    for (auto i = 0u; i < dates.second; ++i)
        std::cout << dates.first[i] << '\n';
}
```

Example output:

```
Fifth Friday dates for 2023 are:
2023-03-31
2023-06-30
2023-09-29
2023-12-29
```

[Demo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nAeQhjsmGn2pgoc1)

It turns out that it is an invariant that every year will have either 4 or 5 months which will have 5 Fridays. So we can efficiently return the results as a pair<array<year_month_day, 5>, unsigned>, where the second member of the pair will always be either 4 or 5.

The first job is just to initialize the array with a bunch of `year_month_day`s. I've arbitrarily chosen `0y/0/0` as a good initialization value. What do I like about this value? One of the things I like is that it is `!ok()`! If I accidentally access `.first[4]` when `.second == 4`, an extra bit of safety is that the resultant `year_month_day` is `!ok()`. So being able to construct these `!ok()` values without an assert or exception is important just for that reason (like a nan). The cost? Nothing. These are compile-time constants.

Next I iterate over each month for the year `y`. The first thing to do is construct the 5<sup>th</sup> Friday for January.  And then increment the loop by 1 month until the year changes.

Now since not every month has a 5<sup>th</sup> Friday, this may not result in a valid date. But in this function the proper response to constructing an invalid date is not an assert nor an exception, nor a snap-back or roll-over. The proper response is to ignore the date and iterate on to the next month. If it is a valid date, then it pushed on to the result.

Many invalid dates were computed during the execution of this program. And none of them represented errors.  And invalid dates were even used within computations (adding a month).  But because the arithmetic is regular, everything just works.

So in summary, it is really best to leave the behavior of invalid dates up to the clever programmer.  Because clever programmers can create all kinds of ingenious solutions to their problems, given the flexibility to do so.

Comment: Do you then consider a `class ok_date` that is always ok? You have already provided the conversion method; why not make a full fledged class?

Comment: @Red.Wave. I think it would be fine (and easy) for clients to create their own `class ok_date`.  I do not think it would be a good idea for `std::chrono` to supply it because there is no clear one right way to design it.

Comment: So, C++ is supposed to have a std *hypothetical* `date` class, while 3rd parties provide *actual* `date` classes.

Comment: I believe I've already covered the rationale and advantages to the C++20 chrono date design in my answer above.  If you don't like it, I'm still very happy for you to use it to build a date class to your liking.  If you don't find it useful at all, you are still free to build your own, or use one of the other date libs that have been developed over the decades.  If you're building your own, here are some high quality fundamental date algorithms to get you started: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html

Comment: IMHO, the first demo should also `assert(date.ok())` to see that it's not only possible to add and subtract a month, but it will also not keep an 'incorrect' state once it was there: https://wandbox.org/permlink/jjes0b0Y9nzflaG9

Comment: Not a bad suggestion thanks.  This also falls out of the statement that a `year_month_day` is a `{year, month, day}` data structure, and not a `{year, month, day, ok_state}` data structure.  `<chrono>` follows the design philosophy of `vector` and `list`:  it advertises its underlying data structures.

Comment: I once debugged a major application outage that was due to a datetime library being fussy about "nonexistent" times when there was no need for it to be. Especially for a stdlib feature it definitely makes sense to let the caller decide what sort of handling they want.

Comment: While `0y/0/0` is not-a-number (`nan`), isn't it more importantly not-a-date (`nad`)?

Comment: This is a great answer for why doesn't it silently change invalid dates to nearby valid dates, and why doesn't it fail an assert...but not really a compelling argument on why it uses a method to signal values that are "not ok" as opposed to throwing an exception.    I'm going to go out on a limb and say it is because exceptions are considered expensive and awkward to handle while having a method to check validity is considered cheap.  I've been out of the C++ loop long enough that I can't say if this is an explicit design choice or if it is uniform across the standard library though...

Comment: I belive the `fifth_friday` example addresses this. You would have to throw an exception and then immediately catch it and do nothing within the for-loop. This would make the code less readable and harder to write. And likely negatively impact compile-time performance. Without sufficient optimization, it would also negatively impact run-time performance. This redesign does get a draw with the most important goal, in that it would not impact correctness:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/coding_guidelines.html. But I see a benefit/cost ratio less than one.